# How to POST dataform data and other datas through a single ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got struck in a point where i have to pass dataForm data's and other datas through a single ajax call, Actually am passing a Blob data by creating a DataFrom object Following code will give you a exact explanation

### my ajax call with data's

```
Fr.voice.export(function(blob){
                  var data = new FormData();
                  data.append('file', blob);
                  console.log(blob);

                  $.ajax({
                    url: "upload1.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                      // Sent to Server
                    }
                  });
                }, "blob");
```

In the above Ajax call am POSTing only the blob data where as i have to pass other data's like

```
id: student_id,
test_no: test_no,
attempt_no: attempt_no,
question_name: "audio" + audioNo.
```

### What i have tried

```
 Fr.voice.export(function(blob){
                  var data = new FormData();
                  data.append('file', blob);
                  console.log(blob);
                   var postData = {
                "audio": base64,
                "id": student_id,
                "test_no": test_no,
                "attempt_no": attempt_no,
                "question_name": "audio" + audioNo
            };

                  $.ajax({
                    url: "upload1.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {data,postData},
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                      // Sent to Server
                    }
                  });
                }, "blob");
```

Am getting [object,object] while am posting the data.

Am new to php and Ajax call, please help me to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You already did `data.append('file', blob);` so just add as many other name value pairs as you want in exactly the same way as that.

Comment: Okay and to get that particular id. i have uploaded the blob inside a folder.I need to append all the other values for example id=20 and filename has to be 20.wav how to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you, i have done it's working

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "upload1.php",
   type: 'POST',
   data: { data: dataVar, postData: postDataVar},
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success: function(data) {
        // Sent to Server
   }
});
```

Comment: again am getting same [Object.Object]